# What's an umbrella term for things like class, struct, interface and enum?

Tags: c#

I know what I typed are keywords, but that umbrella term would also contain things like `if`, `new` or `using`. Can I just call `class`, `interface` etc. types? I feel like that would be confusing because the keyword `class` is being used for declaring types.

Comment: Yes, "Types" is correct.

Comment: To be clear, is what you want a term referring to the **words** `class`, `interface`, not the things those words represent?

Comment: If we call them types. Is the rule "all things i can use `typeof` on are types then correct? Or are there exceptions?

Comment: You can use `typeof` on any type identifier, but there are some types you cannot use `typeof` on, like [anonymous types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types) which do not have an identifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out, the Microsoft documentation calls them "categories of types" here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/common-type-system?redirectedfrom=MSDN#types_in_the_net_framework

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces, classes, structs, and enums are all varieties of [types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/) in .NET.

Generally, words that are used by the language are called keywords. This would include `class`, `interface`, `if`, `new` and many others.

There isn't a term that collectively refers to the keywords that represent types (`class`, `interface`, but not `if`, `for`). I might call these "type declaration keywords".

Comment: Also `delegate` and `record` are types.

Comment: "type declaration keywords" sounds much more descriptive than what Microsoft seems to use ("categories of types")